# What emails to use for AdapativeAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus in sandbox mode?

Tags: paypal

I have a simple issue here. I have a code thats calling an API to check if a given Paypal email is valid. The api is PayPal's AdapativeAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus, url: https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus

If I give it a real paypal email to the sandbox url, it says **unregistered**. But if I move it to production and use the api's prod url, it works! So, whats the issue here? Should I grab a fake email from PP somewhere and use these data to test the api? That would make sense as Paypal might want to protect somehow the accounts from malicious sandbox users..

anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

The Sandbox isn't linked to the live site.  Each site is completely isolated from the other.  Just because an account exists on the live site, it doesn't mean that it exists on the Sandbox (or vice versa).

If you're going to check that an account exists on the Sandbox, you need to create it on the Sandbox first (unless you're trying to check that the account doesn't exist -- in which case, don't create the account).  The easiest way is to use the PayPal Developer Portal -- https://developer.paypal.com.  Log in with the email address and password for your live PayPal account, then go to Applications->Sandbox accounts->Create Account.